# Ruby: writing binary string (7zip) to file. file gets corrupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, binary, 7zip

We're building an application on Ruby on Rails 4 and it's going really fluently, except for this pain-giving issue

In our application we get a Multipart Response from a SOAP request. This response comes from an external party and sends us a 7zip compressed file.  The response has 2 parts, where the second contains a application/octet-stream.

The parts are of the Mail:part type.

When I save the contents of 'part.body.decoded' to a file, I can't open the file with 7zip, because it says the file is damaged.

When I open the generated file in the hex-editor the first lines seem ok.

```
p part.body.decoded.encoding.name # gives => "ASCII-8BIT"

File.open("file.7z", "wb") do |f|
 f.write(part.body.decoded)
end
```

Here are the first HEX lines.

```
37 7A BC AF 27 1C 00 03 EF F2 1B 17 EA FA 03 00
00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BD D9 66 08
00 1E 10 88 27 43 3B A7 F5 C7 75 19 5D F6 A6 E0
```

As a test I created a 7z file myself and read it in a string and wrote it back to a file. This works and gives me a valid 7zip.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Update: when I put the contents of part.body.decoded in a string
str = part.body.decoded #and put the string
p str # I get the string as below (I've deleted the middle section of the string because it has to many characters to post it here)

```
"7z\xBC\xAF'\x1C\x00\x03\xFCpd\x01\xEA\xFA\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006E\x91\x1F\x00\x1E\x10\x88'C;\xA7\xF5\xC7u\x19]\xF6\xA6\xE0\xACC\xD9\xA4\xA0:,4\xE9\xA1\xAD%\x05\\a\xFBq\xA4Z\xEC7\xCC\x8C\x91\xBC?\x80H)\xFBa\xB8\xB8u\xBE\xB2\x1C|`\xA7P|\xC3\xA9\x82\xB3\r\n\xA2\x15\xA2\xDAn\xBB\xB9
```

Comment: Well, it logically follows that `part.body.decoded` does not represent a valid 7z byte stream. Is it Base64 stream instead?  Or you need to write the other part first? Or the other party sends you garbage? Or something else.

Comment: It's not encoded.  37 7A BC AF 27 1C is officially a 7z header (note 37 7A) (side note: it's scary that I can look at "37 7A" and know what that is).  If it was still base 64 encoded that wouldn't be there.  The question I would ask the original poster is "how do you know the 7z file coming from the other side is valid?"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the other party assures me it's a valid 7zip with a xml inside with in this xml Base64 encoded smaller files. I've asked them to email me the original 7zip, but they say they can't. We're not the only party connecting with them, so for now I have to believe them ...

Comment: @MichaelChaney: yeah, presence of null bytes makes it pretty clear that this is no base64. But I needed one more question for the volume. :)

Comment: I've updated the post with a piece of the string. It's to big to post, so I've removed part of the middle section.

Comment: Please don't use "Javascript/HTML/CSS code snippet" button for posting code that is not a mix of JS, HTML and CSS. That thing is meant for runnable pieces of code (you press a button and see it work). For all other code (and things like that binary output), use "code sample" button.

Comment: The next question would be "is it complete"?  At this point, I would write a parser to show the high level chunks in the 7z file along with a type and length and set it loose on this to see if the file is complete or otherwise corrupt.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thnx for the tip

Comment: @MichaelChaney that's what I'm going to do

Comment: I agree with Michael, those first 6 bytes look correct for a 7z file. Can you make the request using a soap testing tool, save that file and compare them?

Comment: @MarcRohloff that was a superb tip. Just ran the same SOAP request with SoapGUI and this is the first line: "7z\xBC\xAF'\u001C\u0000\u0003\x8D\xB4\ek\xEA\xFA\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000h\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\xBD\xF8\xB9\u0000\u001E\u0010\x88'C;   The response is different coding. Would it be possible that the Savon Soap gem is doing something with the raw response?

Comment: Possibly. How did you print that out? Also how did you get your 'hex' output in the original post? Also does SoapGUI let you save that to a file?

Comment: @MarcRohloff SoapGUI has an option to save the data to a file. When I rename that file as file.7z I can open it as a valid archive. When I read that file in a string with Ruby and put it to the console I get the following (small piece of output as an example): \u0004\na\x9F\x9F\u0017X\a\xC0\xC7w\xE9\r*q\n\b(\xAD\u0012   When I put the response of the Ruby request to a string and to the console I see (same piece of output): x04\r\na\x9F\x9F\x17X\a\xC0\xC7w\xE9\r\n*q\r\n\b(\xAD\x12  The line endings are different here. That's also what I see if I compare the written files with vbindiff..

Answer (score 1):

Solved :-) The Savon 2 Soap Gem depends on the Mail Gem (max. version 2.5). In the Mail gem there is a bug, which touches the raw binary reponse (it ads line-ends). I've forked the Mail gem and made adaptions (to be found in the higher version of Mail (which Savon doesn't use)) and added 'my' Mail gem to my gemfile. 
Thnx to all commenters for their tips!